# php login script using specific username and password by session id

Tags: php, session, authentication, sessionid

I wish some help .
I need a php script using session id to redirect a specific username and password log in 
to a specific html form as no one except that user can reach links without logging in by this username and password (i.e no one can copy the link after logging in at another browser and proceed) . Something like admin area or something.
(note : i'll specify name and password by myself not by retrieving it from database ,So no SQL scripts needed)
I searched too much in that and couldn't find something helps .
appreciate ur  effort in advance .

Comment: what do you mean by "using session id"? you really mean "session_id()" or what?

Comment: Please tell us what you have already tried and where you are stuck. We are not doing your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

On `special_form.php` and/or other similar pages put something like this:

```
check_login();
```

Where `check_login()` is something like this:

```
function check_login() {

    if ($_SESSION['login'] == true AND !empty($_SESSION['user_id')) {

        if ($_SESSION['username'] != 'MyUser' OR $_SESSION['password'] != 'MyPass') {

            header('Location: http://www.domain.com/login.php');
        }

    } else {
        header('Location: http://www.domain.com/login.php');
    }
}
```

Now, on `login-process.php` write something like this:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];

if ($_SESSION['username'] == 'MyUser' AND $_SESSION['password'] == 'MyPass') {

    header('Location: http://www.domain.com/special_form.php');
}

// normal login process code
```

I just hope that I've understood your problem correctly. Give me some hints if I'm wrong somewhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this on top of all pages to check if logged in:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'] || 
   !$_SESSION['loggedin']==1) header('Location: http://website.com/login.php');
```

Html form on login.php

```
<?php
//And just check post variables from form:
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(strcmp($_POST['username'], 'Your username') == 0 &&
      (strcmp($_POST['password'], 'Your password') == 0) {
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
        header('Location: http://website.com/youareloggedin.php');
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Some tips:

- do not write anything to page before calling header function, it will break it.
- A blank action on form will send data to itself, make sure php is on top (it is generally easier to keep all php on top and use inline php when needed e.g. `<?=functionorvariable()?>`
- strcmp compares two strings, if they are equal it will give you zero as a return value.
- always use isset to check if form was actually submitted on page instead of checking values.
- you should add in error checking for checking post values, to see if they are empty or whatever, it is good practice.
- learn by doing, please study the structure of this program and see how it is clearly written, it's intentions are clear. Always follow the clarity route when coding.

Good luck